# How does spotify keep the track timer and controls synched across multiple browser windows?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I'm trying to make a localhost only webapp using Dash. I know things like electron exist for this, but I'm more comfortable with dash and pyinstaller for my internal application. I want to open something in a separate window and control it from another window and vice versa. I notice spotify is able to do this in open.spotify.com. They even have the time on a playing song synced in all the windows at once.

How are they doing it? Is it WebWorkers?

Comment: Could be Broadcast Channel API

Comment: @JaromandaX Looks promising! Thanks I'm reading about that now.